# Edit weight of block without using drag and drop

Tags: 7, blocks

I'm attempting to reorder blocks. I understand that it can be done by dragging and dropping on the block structure page, however I have a limitation.

When saving, the order isn't saved. This is most likely because there is a very large number of blocks and the server can't handle that many inputs in one form. So it just reverts to it's original position. I do not have access to the server so I'm unable to make the changes to allow the server to handle that many inputs.
I also do not have access to the mySQL database.

I'd like to be able to change the weight manually within the block, but weight is not a field I can edit when attempting to edit that specific block.

Is there a way to add this field? Or is there another possible way to perform this action?

Comment: The weight is in the database on the `block`-table. (In fact one block can have multiple rows, one for each theme.) Does it have to be done in the Drupal UI?

Comment: I don't have access to the mySQL database either.

Comment: Does it work when you toggle the weight field on the block overview page? At the right top of the block page there is a `Show row weights` link to toggle drag-drop and the weight field.

Comment: It does not. I get the same result. Is there a way to toggle the show row weight within one block, so I don't have to submit the weight for every single block at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very hacky way to do it but I managed to achieve my goal. Through the dev tools on my browser I removed the html of every row of the block table except for the block I wanted to edit. I then changed the weight and submitted.

This worked since only one input was being submitted instead of over 1000

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by using context name in `hook_context_load_alter()` and tweak it.

`/**
 * Implementation of hook_context_load_alter()
 */
function mymodule_context_load_alter(&$context) {
  if ($context->name == 'my_context_name_from_the_ui') {
    $context->reactions['block']['blocks']['my_block_name']['weight'] = -99;
  }
}`